# how to display title of websites in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get title of different site. like this.

```
localhost:1234/index/?url=google.com&url=www.yahoo.com/&url=twitter.com
```

if i got to this url it crawl on all the mention site in the url and display title of website.

```
 - Google    
 - Yahoo
 - Twitter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var Urls = 'localhost:1234/index/?url=google.com&url=www.yahoo.com/&url=twitter.com';
    // remove all special characters like '/' '&' and '='
    Urls = Urls.replace(/\&/g, '').replace(/\//g, '').replace(/\=/g, '');
    // split it based on url 
    Urls = Urls.split('url');
    //delete first element as its not required
    delete Urls[0]
    Urls.forEach(function (url) {       
    //split each element based on '.'
        url = url.split('.');
        url.forEach(function (ele) {
            // if its not 'www' and 'com' 
            if (ele !== 'www' && ele !== 'com') {
                // the title of url
                console.log(ele);
            }
        })
    })
```

you need to remove all special character as above using regular expression and if urls contains ".org" or ".in" .. etc, then that also need to include inside if condition

Comment: That's not the proper answer. I said it should to specified url to get title from that website.

Comment: i think these can help u [link1](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth),[link2](https://rapiddg.com/blog/calling-rest-api-nodejs-script).